# Upload blob file to S3 from javascript code without revealing secret key

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I am using [a link](http://www.cheynewallace.com/uploading-to-s3-with-angularjs/) to upload blob file to S3 server directly, but I do not want to reveal secret access key as done in this link, please provide how can it be done.

Any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks !!

Comment: What have you tried? Check this http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/

Comment: Yes I went through this, but could not get much out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some potential options:

**1. Use a pre-signed URL**

From [Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html):

> A pre-signed URL gives you access to the object identified in the URL, provided that the creator of the pre-signed URL has permissions to access that object. That is, if you receive a pre-signed URL to upload an object, you can upload the object only if the creator of the pre-signed URL has the necessary permissions to upload that object.

**2. Generate temporary credentials**

Use the [AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to generate temporary credentials with limited permissions. These credentials can permit specific activities (eg upload to a specific location within Amazon S3) for a limited time period (eg 5 minutes). The danger of exposing these credentials would be relatively minor (since they can only do what your web page was permitting anyway).

Use either `AssumeRole` to assume permissions defined within an IAM role, or use `GetSessionToken` to scope-down permissions based on a current IAM user.

**3. Use web identity federation**

[Web identity federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/web-identity-federation.html) permits authentication via a 3rd-party provider such as Google+, Facebook and Amazon. The user authenticates to one of these services, and your website can use that identity to permit access to AWS services. The only credentials you will expose are related only to those users themselves.